# Mapping schemes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector-graphics, zooming, pan

we are developing project, which contains map for registration some kind of resources of conpany. Map based in OpenLayers (client-side) and geoserver (server-side).

But now, we need to display special scheme, which displays connection cable with cable and cable with devices (it is about telecom). Something like at the picture, but it must will be a global scheme (now it displays local for each specific block in openLayesr map). Scheme must be able to zoom and pan, and support partial loading information in bounds (for better performance, because full scheme can contain big array of objects).

I think, it may be displayed in special layer in OpenLayers, but i think, it will be some problem with coordinate system, because we need 2d in scheme, but OL uses special other for geomapping.

I need for advise, which prepared component in JavaScript can i use, or may be i can force OL use 2d coordinate and drawing vector graphics? Or, at least, which most optimal solution with prepared functionality.

Comment: Which Openlayers version?

Comment: version: Release 2.13.1

Comment: Ok, we decided, then we will use OpenLayers as base app, scheme will display with kinetic js, because  we have implemented functionality modules in whose libs. 
I wand to decide in OpenLayers guru: can i draw html5 canvas graphics in OL maps as a Feature.Vactor  or, may be, there is another way to do this?